# How do I solve problem of my iMac now refusing to let me access Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

Immediately after a software upgrade to my iMac, an error message appeared: "Bitcoin Core quit unexpectedly" and I followed the instructions to "reopen" and the error kept repeating. How do I get back on bitcoin core?

Comment: What is in `debug.log`?

Comment: Do you have a [backup of your wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/secure-your-wallet#backup) (or better, many regularly made backups) and a written note of your master private key?